# PHP MYSQLI Login Not Working

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication

The `Script` Always Returns Failure(Regardless Of Correct/Incorrect User Information. Nothing Is Wrong with any other files. The `Config` File works and is just a starter of the `sql` `connection` and selects the `database`.

```
@include('../settings/config.php');
if (!@include('../settings/config.php')) {
    die("<center>Login Failed</center>");
}

//======================================================================
// POST Check(Isset submit comes from html form)
//======================================================================
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// Sanitize All POST Fields
$_POST = array_map('trim', $_POST);
$_POST = array_map('strip_tags',$_POST);

$login_form_user = $_POST['login_user'];
$login_form_pass = $_POST['login_pass'];
// Testing Only
echo("
<center>
Your Username is: $login_form_user!
<br>
Your Password is: $login_form_pass!
</center>
");
//======================================================================
// Input/Database Check
//======================================================================
$user_fetch = <<<LOGIN
SELECT `id` FROM `users` 
WHERE `username`='$login_form_user' 
AND `password`='$login_form_pass' 
LIMIT 1
LOGIN;

$user_result = $sql_connection->query($user_fetch);
if(!$user_result) {
    die("<center>Cannot Execute SQL Login Query</center>");
}

if ($sql_connection->num_rows == 1) {
echo("<center>User $login_form_user Exists</center>");
}


 if($row = $user_result->fetch_assoc()) {
 if(($row['username'] === $login_form_user) && ($row['password'] === $login_form_pass)) {
// Login Is Successful
echo("<center>Login Successful</center>");
} else {
echo("<center>Login Failed</center>");
}
}

} else {
// No Direct File Access Allowed
unset($_POST);
die('No Direct File Access Allowed!');
}
?>
```

Comment: Show us how you get `$sql_connection` (use fake login creds of course). Not knowing what it is makes it more difficult to assess some of the code.

Comment: Amon please *do not change your question to implement fixes from the answers*.  This invalidates the answers and will make it impossible for people who come across this later to learn from your mistakes!

Comment: $sql_connection = new mysqli($settings['mysql_host'], $settings['mysql_user'], $settings['mysql_pass']);

$sql_connection->select_db($settings['mysql_data']);

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if(($row['username'] === $login_form_pass)...
```

To:

```
if(($row['username'] === $login_form_user)...
```

Comment: That's too vague. What exactly happens?

Comment: You've changed your question to apply my solution. Please don't do that because it invalidates the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo error in this line please change it

```
if(($row['username'] === $login_form_pass) && ($row['password'] === $login_form_pass)) 

$row['username'] === $login_form_user// you are comparing it with $login_form_pass
```

Comment: @Amon try by replacing === with ==

Comment: and also i assume there is only one combination of row with username and password which you have entered.